# C#/.NET System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, properly referenced as directive but not recognized in code

Tags: c#, .net, configurationmanager

So in this particular C# helper, I have the following listed at the top of the file:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

When I try to reference it in the c# code (within the same file),

```
static readonly string apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiKey"];
```

**The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context.**

Why would this be? `System.Configuration` is used all over the place in this application, but isn't being recognized in this particular file.

If I go to the Manage NuGet packages panel and search 'configuration manager', the top choice is 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager'. Even the oldest available version has a .NETFramework dependency of 4.6.1, whereas this application uses 4.5.1 so downloading it is not possible.

Is there something I am overlooking here?

Any and all input appreciated.

Comment: Did you add a reference to the System.Configuration.dll in your references window? That class is in that assembly but the namespace is common to other system types

Comment: As for the references window, any time I go to 'Add References' I get `Error HRRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM Component`. It's VS2017, but have never been able to get rid of that error when trying to access the References panel.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a reference to System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are getting error in the Add References window, try editing the .csproj to add the reference (along with other references) in the Reference ItemGroup like:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Beautiful, that was the way to go. Updated vs2017 to latest version, deleted .vs folder, no dice. Opened up the .csproj for that particular Helper, added that `Reference Include=` line, and we're good to go. Thank you so much!